# How to implement Polymorphism using a vector as function parameter in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm stuck on the following.

Let's say we have a base class:

```cpp
class A{

    public:
        virtual void myfunc(vector <A> *a){
            // nothing to do here
    }

};
```

And two subclasses:

```
class B : public A {
    public:
        void myfunc(vector <A> *a){
            //some other code
    }
};

class C : public A {
    public:
        void myfunc(vector <A> *a){
            //some other code
    }
};
```

Here's another class where I create misc functions:

```cpp
class D {
    public:
        void dosomething(vector <A> * c){
           // i need to call upon polymorphism here so myfunc is dynamically called for B or C
    }

};
```

My problem lies in class `D`. How can I achieve polymorphism there? I've tried a lot, but I end up still calling the base class's function.

Comment: Unrelated: `Class` is spelled `class` and each class definition should end with `;`

Comment: It's `public` not `publich` and your `class D` isn't inheriting `class A`

Comment: You don't have any objects of type B or C left once you slice stuff off to put them in a vector of A objects. So nothing to be polymorphic with.

Comment: I also don't know exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes sorry for the typos.
I'm using an IDE so there's no such typos in the code.

Comment: You might consider a vector of smart pointers instead for this.

Comment: Your function `D::dosomething()` has no access to any objects of type `B` or `C`, so it is unclear how you plan on calling their members.  Perhaps you are unaware that `std::vector<A>` can only hold objects of type `A`?

Comment: _"sorry for the typos_" - No need. Just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72776050/edit) the question and fix them.

Comment: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/631266)

Comment: *I'm new to C++...* You will likely benefit from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Answer (score 2):

In C++, **polymorphism** requires using a pointer or a reference to be able to access the polymorphic behavior.  The pointer can be a smart pointer, like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

With the `vector<A>`, that vector can only hold A objects.  It cannot hold a B or C object.

Here's an example changing the parameter to `vector<unique_ptr<A>>`.  (Also, passing a parameter by *pointer* indicates that a `nullptr` is an acceptable value unless indicated otherwise such as by a comment or an `assert`.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::make_unique;
using std::ostream;
using std::string;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::vector;

namespace {

struct A {
    virtual ~A();
    virtual void myfunc(vector<unique_ptr<A>> *a) {
        if (a)
            cout << "A has a vector with " << a->size() << " objects\n";
        else
            cout << "A had a null vector\n";
    }
    virtual auto name() const -> string {
        return "base A";
    }
    virtual auto color() const -> string {
        return "azure";
    }
};

A::~A() = default;

struct B : A {
    void myfunc(vector<unique_ptr<A>>* a) override {
        if (a) {
            for (auto&& x : *a) {
                if (x)
                    cout << "B saw a " << x->name() << "\n";
                else
                    cout << "B saw a null pointer\n";
            }
        } else {
            cout << "B had a null vector\n";
        }
    }
    auto name() const -> string override {
        return "child B";
    }
    auto color() const -> string override {
        return "byzantine";
    }
};

struct C : A {
    void myfunc(vector<unique_ptr<A>>* a) override {
        if (a) {
            for (auto&& x : *a) {
                if (x)
                    cout << "C saw the color " << x->color() << "\n";
                else
                    cout << "C saw a null pointer\n";
            }
        } else {
            cout << "B had a null vector\n";
        }
    }
    auto name() const -> string override {
        return "child C";
    }
    auto color() const -> string override {
        return "cerulean";
    }
};

struct Ord {
    int nth = 0;
    auto operator++() -> Ord& { ++nth; return *this; }
    friend auto operator<<(ostream& out, Ord const& o) -> ostream& {
        out << o.nth;
        if (o.nth == 1) out << "st";
        else if (o.nth == 2) out << "nd";
        else if (o.nth == 3) out << "rd";
        else out << "th";
        return out;
    }
};

class D {
public:
    void dosomething(vector<unique_ptr<A>>* a){
        // i need to call upon polymorphism here so myfunc is dynamically called for B or C
        if (a) {
            Ord ord;
            for (auto&& x : *a) {
                cout << "D::dosomething with " << ++ord << "\n";

                if (x) {
                    x->myfunc(a);
                } else {
                    cout << "D had a null in the vector\n";
                }

                cout << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            cout << "D had a null vector\n";
        }
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<A>> a;
    a.push_back(make_unique<A>());
    a.push_back(make_unique<B>());
    a.push_back(make_unique<C>());
    a.push_back(unique_ptr<A>());
    a.push_back(make_unique<A>());
    D d;
    d.dosomething(&a);
}
```

Comment: Thank  you. your answer helped me understand why is wasn't working.
I reviewed another answer and i clearly see that this is about object slicing. A subject i wasn't introduced so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you're after, but here you have a small example including:

- A hierarchy of classes `A` (base), and `B`, and `C` (derived). I've made `A` pure virtual.
- `B` and `C` classes implement `myfunc`. `B` prints the *int* it holds, and `C` prints the *char* it holds.
- A class `D` with a `dosomething` method that receives a vector of `A*`, and calls `myfunc` on each of them. **Here's where runtime polymorphism kicks in**. I've used `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of `A*`.
- I've also used structs instead of classes and changed `myfunc`'s signature just to avoid some typing.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/93d1Yss9n)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    virtual void myfunc() const = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    explicit B(int i) : i_{i} {}
    int i_{};
    virtual void myfunc() const override {
        fmt::print("B: {}\n", i_);
    }
};

struct C : public A {
    explicit C(char c) : c_{c} {}
    char c_{};
    virtual void myfunc() const override {
        fmt::print("C: {}\n", c_);
    }
};

struct D {
    static void dosomething(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>& v_a) {
        for (auto&& a : v_a) {
            a->myfunc();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> v{};
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>(555));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<C>('f'));
    
    D::dosomething(v);
}

// Outputs:
//   B: 555
//   C: f
```

Comment: Thanks. Going to explore unique_ptr and shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `vector<B>` is not a `vector<A>` simply based on `B` is an `A`. Therefore, you can either:

- have a vector of pointers, i.e., `vector<A*>` in `dosomething()`
- have a vector of variants, i.e. `vector<variant<B, C>>` if you're sure it's B or C, but then use variant interface in `dosomething` (likely visitors or `std::get<>()`)
- in the quite usual case when the order of B and C elements is not important in processing, have a tuple of vectors, `tuple<vector<B>, vector<C>>`. This is likely faster as there's no polymorphic overhead.

Comment: `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` are better than raw pointers in the vector. Somebody has to delete the objects when the vector goes out of scope.

Comment: A variant of vectors won't work here. A variant stores one or the other, not both at the same time. Perhaps you were thinking of a tuple? Polymorphic overhead is small - any performance gains from this approach are more likely to be from improved locality of reference. It does make the source code more cumbersome, though.

Comment: @AviBerger yes, thanks for spotting it, fixed. Polimorphic overhead is quite high actually - yes, memory allocation/locality is higher by default allocator, but you can work around it via using your own allocator, something that many projects does. I don't think it's more cumbersome - you can write your own `foreach(tupleOfVectors& tvv, T lambda);` that calls lambda with static type references -, but you do lose relative order of elements across types.